# Google Maps Directions API - Marking a point x km from starting point

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am trying to build a web application to show the position of users in a map, who are participating in a virtual trek. These treks are long distance one, typically >500km, on highways. The information I know is the trek route (start, end along with way points) and distance he has covered with respect to the starting point.

How in GMaps V3, I can plot the marker, which is x km from the starting point, along the drawn direction by Google maps.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out this. The technique involves getting the individual lat long steps and incrementally calculate the distance. The individual steps are close enough to do a straight line approximation between two consecutive points.
A reverse traverse is done for the last overshooting point.

The error rate is 0.1%, irrespective of the distance. ie a distance of 2000 km will be off by 2 km on map.

```
//Returns the Google LatLng object corresponding to distanceInKM for the given route.
//Params : directionResult : The google.maps.DirectionsResult obtained from DirectionService.route(request:DirectionsRequest, callback:function(DirectionsResult, DirectionsStatus))
//distanceInKM : The distance offset with respect to the starting point.
function getLatLngOnRoute(directionResult, distanceInKM) {
    var lastPos=directionResult.routes[0].legs[0].steps[0].path[0]; var currPos;
    var distance=0.0;
    distanceInKM*=1000;
    //Will not consider alternate routes. 
    for (var j=0; j<directionResult.routes[0].legs.length; j++) {
        //There may be multiple legs, each corresponding to one way point. If there are no way points specified, there will be a single leg
        for (var k=0; k<directionResult.routes[0].legs[j].steps.length; k++) {
            //There will be multiple sub legs or steps
            for (var l=0; l<directionResult.routes[0].legs[j].steps[k].path.length; l++) {
                currPos=directionResult.routes[0].legs[j].steps[k].path[l];
                //Calculate the distance between two lat lng sets. 
                distance+=google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(lastPos, currPos);
                if (distance>distanceInKM) {
                    //If the exact point comes between two points, use distance to lat-lng conversion
                    var heading=google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(currPos, lastPos);
                    var l= google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(currPos, distance-distanceInKM, heading);
                    return l;
                }
                lastPos=currPos;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707473/draw-route-x-kilometers-from-origin) topic set me in the correct direction.